# React how render data after submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Anybody know how can i right send my form without refresh page. All data save in DB, but not render after send

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = document.forms[0];
        console.log(this.state);
        axios.post('/api/departments', this.state)
            .then(response => {
                const{departments} = this.state;
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({departments});
                form.reset();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    };
```

And maybe here problem too

Comment: please check this: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to set the department property when you get the response, but you actually never do that. You are just calling the department property, then console logging the response and then setting the department property to the same old value. You need to do this:

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = document.forms[0];
        axios.post('/api/departments', this.state)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({departments: response}, () => {
                    form.reset();
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    };
```

This example would work if the response has the new value for department. I'm just trying to assume what you want to do, but you get the idea. You never actually updated the state of your application.